# Regex to compile all text between tabs/indents within paragraphs in Python

Tags: python, regex, docx, python-re

Apologies in advance if this is somewhere else but I've been looking and I'm not good with regex. I'm using regex to compile sentences from a word document containing paragraphs. I need to get specifically the text between 2 indents, or if someone can help me figure out the current regex I have (which is shown later), then that will also work. For example, from the following text;

[image: Input Document]

Here is the image as plain text, though I can't get the formatting the same:

1. A method, comprising:

   storing a first data related to an operation style of a transport in a first area;

   storing a second data related to an operation style of the transport in a second area; wherein the first and second data is based on a combined energy consumption efficiency as the transport maneuvers through the first and second area; and

   modifying functionality of the transport based on the combined energy consumption efficiency.
2. The method of claim 1, comprising modifying functionality of the transport to operate at a greatest combined efficiency consumption efficiency while in compliance with one or more of social necessities and vehicular laws.

And here is the text that is actually read in from my function:

> 1. A method, comprising:            storing a first data related to an operation style of a transport in a first area;             storing a second data related to an operation style of the transport in a second area; wherein the first and second data is based on a combined energy consumption efficiency as the transport maneuvers through the first and second area; and             modifying functionality of the transport based on the combined energy consumption efficiency.2.     The method of claim 1, comprising modifying functionality of the transport to operate at a greatest combined efficiency consumption efficiency while in compliance with one or more of social necessities and vehicular laws.

All of this is output into one line when I print the read in text from the .docx file

I need to extract the following lines:

> storing a first data related to an operation style of a transport in a first area;
>
> storing a second data related to an operation style of the transport in a second area; wherein the first and second data is based on a combined energy consumption efficiency as the transport maneuvers through the first and second area; and
>
> modifying functionality of the transport based on the combined energy consumption efficiency.

My current regex pattern is as follows:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[ \t]+([^\s.;]+\s*)+[.;]+")
```

As mentioned before, If someone can help me figure this regex out so that I read to either a semicolon or a period, then that would be great, otherwise, I understand that a part of my problem is that I have [ \t] as opposed to just [\t], however when I remove the space, I get no output. Additionally, the current regex is supposed to read to semi colons, but I am instead going to read to the next indent so that I can just parse the sentences afterwards and remove unnecessary information. If it helps at all, my current output is as shown here:

[image: Output]

Here is just the raw text of output:

> A method, comprising:            storing a first data related to an
> operation style of a transport in a first  storing a second data
> related to an operation style of the transport in a second  first and
> second data is based on a combined energy consumption efficiency as
> the transport maneuvers through the first and second  and            
> modifying functionality of the transport based on the combined energy
> consumption  method of claim 1, comprising modifying functionality of
> the transport to operate at a greatest combined efficiency consumption
> efficiency while in compliance with one or more of social necessities
> and vehicular

Each line of text in the image is a single output from my code. Any text that isn't recognized from the original excerpt from the .docx is simply more of the text within the .docx file.

Finally, here is the code I'm currently working with:

```
def find_matches(text):
    print(text)
    pattern = re.compile(r"[ \t]+([^\s.;]+\s*)+[.;]+")
    return capitalize([m.group() for m in re.finditer(pattern, text)])


for match in find_matches(text=docText):
    ct += 1
    match_words = match.split(" ")
    match = " ".join(match_words[:-1])
    print(match)
```

So, all I need is some regex to read from intend to indent, and again, apologies if this is somewhere else, I simply could not find it.

I'm adding this bit as I've finally got some output with a regex pattern, however it seems to all be gibberish which I'm assuming is because of the encoding. Here is the code that I have to show this:

```
doc = open('P.docx', mode='r', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
docText = doc.read()
pattern = r"^[^.;]*\s{2,}([^\s.;]*(?:\s+[^\s.;]+)+[.;])"
print(re.findall(pattern, docText, re.MULTILINE))
```

And this is just a bit (because there is a lot) of the output that I get from using this:

> '½ú\x04Ü\x13\x8eÕ\nõ+;', '\x7fîÙ(\x11\x90\x85íÆ\x83Bs\x15Ü\xa0g\x03i\x00a\x070§¬gÃo\x18Ë\x9a\x81i[¡\x8eÃ{\x96FÃ9\x9f\x8aãð6°AÏ>ö·\x98+\x80e·!f\x8d\x0e{\x12W\x1eéÝ}iûÍ¨½niü>Ú¶mB¥»\tÜÀªÓÿº$í}b^3¢¡7\t\x1amwR\x19ò\x96\x83"Hf\x0fòÑ«NÀ=áXÝP½²£ç\x1a\x01ZÁÍEÃÌ4ÒÄ\x90-dÌìáy½Þ|yFÕ,4ýÂÍ.', "ð`\x9c\n\x99´-Á:bÒÒY²O\x86\x88\x06'\x93°Îx4û§'?Ì÷\xad\x00m{N¸r6a\x86×8Û\x9drâúÙÄ9\x85\x91\x0c-;",

Comment: Please show your input as plain text, a string with quotes, [rather than a screenshot](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Whitespace and every character in the string matters or the regex can break. Thanks.

Comment: I did what I could, though I couldn't quite exactly match the original formatting.

Comment: Are you reading the string into your Python program at some point? You could `print(repr(s))` and copy-paste that, with quotes, into a triple-backticked code block. That way, we know what we're dealing with here. It'll probably save you a lot of time in the long run dealing with irrelevant/buggy answers that make assumptions about your use case (or not getting many quality answers at all).

Comment: The strings that I'm outputting? Or the single string of text from the word document?

Comment: the fact that you have to use `[ \t]`, with a space included, indicates that the "tab characters" in your text may not actually be tab characters

Comment: @JimmyWede the string you're applying the regex pattern to, presumably read in from the document you've shown a screenshot of. But yeah, the output also must be in text to be of much use. There's no reason for any of this to be anything but raw, well-formatted, runnable code. Anything less is just making folks do guesswork. Please and thanks!

Comment: @TallChuck  I've added raw text of output of read-in text as well as a snippet of my actual code.

Comment: @JimmyWede Can you do something like this - [`\t+[^\r\n]+`](https://regex101.com/r/h32f8e/1) - [code](https://regex101.com/r/h32f8e/1/codegen?language=python)

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh  No output from that

Comment: Please let me know if there's anything else that you want me to add to the post to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: I don't get it. The regex that I have shared does match what you intend to match - a tab followed by 1+ occurrences of any character which is not a newline character

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh  Yes, but it seems that my code is reading in the text from the .docx file a bit strangely.

Comment: Try it like this `[ \t]{2,}(?:[^\s.;]+\s*)+[.;]` https://regex101.com/r/VGWngP/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might start the match with 1 or more spaces or tabs, and capture what you want in a group.

```
^[ \t]+([^\s.;]+(?:\s+[^\s.;]+)*[.;])
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[ \t]+` Match 1+ tabs or spaces
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s.;]+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars except `.` or `;`
  - `(?:\s+[^\s.;]+)*` Optionally repeat matching 1+ whitespace chars and  1+ non whitespace chars except `.` or `;`
  - `[.;]` Match either `.` or `;`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3XDytb/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/v5lGAq)

Example

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
pattern = r"^[ \t]{2,}([^\s.;]+(?:\s+[^\s.;]+)+[.;])"

s = ("1. A method, comprising:\n\n"
     "      storing a first data related to an operation style of a transport in a first area;\n\n"
     "     storing a second data related to an operation style of the transport in a second area; wherein the first and second data is based on a combined energy consumption efficiency as the transport maneuvers through the first and second area; and \n\n"
     "     modifying functionality of the transport based on the combined energy consumption efficiency.\n\n"
     "2. The method of claim 1, comprising modifying functionality of the transport to operate at a greatest combined efficiency consumption efficiency while in compliance with one or more of social necessities and vehicular laws. \n\n"
     "And here is the text that is actually read in from my function:\n\n"
     "> 1. A method, comprising:            storing a first data related to an operation style of a transport in a first area;             storing a second data related to an operation style of the transport in a second area; wherein the first and second data is based on a combined energy consumption efficiency as the transport maneuvers through the first and second area; and             modifying functionality of the transport based on the combined energy consumption efficiency.2.     The method of claim 1, comprising modifying functionality of the transport to operate at a greatest combined efficiency consumption efficiency while in compliance with one or more of social necessities and vehicular laws.\n")

result = re.findall(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE)
pprint(result, width=100)
```

Output

```
['storing a first data related to an operation style of a transport in a first area;',
 'storing a second data related to an operation style of the transport in a second area;',
 'modifying functionality of the transport based on the combined energy consumption efficiency.']
```

Comment: My issue might be that I'm reading input from a .docx file, and so for whatever reason, this regex also doesn't work. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation though, but sadly this still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @JimmyWede Did you get any match at all?

Comment: Nothing. No output other than "[ ]"

Comment: Do you have a link to the docx file with that part of the text?

Comment: See if this works for you. It just has an edited word document with only the stuff I've shown in my original post. https://www.mediafire.com/file/rnk44ul8f5fg6wj/TempP.docx/file

Comment: @JimmyWede I copies the content from the word file to a .txt file, and changed the pattern  to `^[^.;]*\s{2,}([^\s.;]*(?:\s+[^\s.;]+)+[.;])` https://regex101.com/r/Ff0toT/1 See this demo code https://ideone.com/ncD4F9

Comment: I realize my problem may have been how I was taking in the input. I was using the Document library and it didn't seem to like how it was encoded perhaps, but now using the more common way of opening with the open(filename, mode, encoding), I do get an output, however it just looks like a bunch of gibberish. I will add an edit to my post showing this.

Comment: @JimmyWede Are you opening the `.docx` file with Pyton? I am not sure if that works. Maybe there is a way to convert that using a different encoding?

Comment: That's what I was wondering, but yes, I've added what I'm doing/the output to my original post if you'd like to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @JimmyWede Ok, try it with this code https://ideone.com/7IhgvZ

Comment: That seems to work, thank you so much. If I wanted to edit the regex to work so that is took the entire second indented bit that goes "storing a second... the first and second area; and", how would I go about that? I can't recall if I need that entire bit or if it's just until the first semicolon

Comment: @JimmyWede In that case, if there is one a single line you can use `^[^.;]*\s{2,}(.+)` https://regex101.com/r/gevonB/1